# How to generate a list from a pandas dataframe with column name and values as nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

How to generate a list from a pandas dataframe  with column name and values as nested list?
this is my dataframe:

```
  a b c  d
0 1 5 9  13
1 2 6 10 14
2 3 7 11 15
3 4 8 12 16
```

i would like to generate a list

```
list1 = [[a,1], [a,2], [a,3],[a,4]]
list2 = [[b,5], [b,6], [b,7],[b,8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use a list comprehension for that.

- For `list1`

  ```
  list1 = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(['a'] * len(df), df['a'])]

  [Out]: [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['a', 4]]
  ```
- For `list2`:

  ```
  list2 = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(['b'] * len(df), df['b'])]

  [Out]: [['b', 5], ['b', 6], ['b', 7], ['b', 8]]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
     'b': {0: 5, 1: 6, 2: 7, 3: 8},
     'c': {0: 9, 1: 10, 2: 11, 3: 12},
     'd': {0: 13, 1: 14, 2: 15, 3: 16}})

lists = [[[c,x] for x in col] for c,col in df.iteritems()]

print(lists[0]) # [['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['a', 4]]
print(lists[1]) # [['b', 5], ['b', 6], ['b', 7], ['b', 8]]
```

`lists` is a list containing the results corresponding to each column.

---

Row-major format:

```
lists = [list(zip(r.index,r)) for _,r in df.iterrows()]
```

Note that the innermost "lists" in this formulation are actually tuples. To have lists at both layers, you could do the following:

```
lists = [list(map(list,zip(r.index,r))) for _,r in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: list1 = [[a,1], [b,5], [c,9],[d,13]]
How can I get this  for each row?

Comment: One way to go from the answer that I gave to this new format is with `lists_2 = list(zip(*lists))`

Comment: @Ben For a way to get this formulation directly, see my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []
df.apply(lambda x:lst.append([[x.name,i] for i in x]))
print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

```
[['a', 1], ['a', 2], ['a', 3], ['a', 4]]
[['b', 5], ['b', 6], ['b', 7], ['b', 8]]
[['c', 9], ['c', 10], ['c', 11], ['c', 12]]
[['d', 13], ['d', 14], ['d', 15], ['d', 16]]
```